# Struggling with pointers to Assign new contents to a vector

Tags: c++, class, object, vector, assign

Okay so what I am trying to do is add an instance of a class to a specific index of a vector. This index can either be initially non-existent, or be an existing index which has been cleared and is having a new class instance being written to that position.

Below is the function that I have been using to try and write these instances to the vector, and commented at the bottom you can see the other 2 methods that I tried to use, Obviously with push_back only being able to add new vectors at the end.

I have a feeling that assign may only be able to add data to existing elements? And that insert may add a new element and shift the existing elements down instead of overwriting. Just want a bit of clarity on this, as the C++ tutorials have started confusing me.

Also, what would be the correct way to reference/defreference/call the Person vector (in this case being referred to as "allthePeople"), so that it is possible to change its data?

```
void createnewPerson(int assignID, RECT startingpoint, vector<Person>* allthePeople, int framenumber) {
    Person newguy(assignID, startingpoint, framenumber);

    std::cout << "New Person ID number: " << newguy.getIDnumber() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "New Person Recent Frame:  " << newguy.getlastframeseen() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "New Person Recent history bottom:  " << newguy.getrecenthistory().bottom << std::endl;
    int place = assignID - 1;

    //This is where I am confused about referencing/dereferencing
    allthePeople->assign(allthePeople->begin() + place, newguy);
    //allthePeople->insert(place, newguy);
    //allthePeople->push_back(newguy);
}
```

Also just to clarify, "place" is always 1 less than "assignID", because vector positions start at 0, and I simply wanted to start their ID numbers at 1 instead of 0.

-------------EDIT : ADDED IF LOOP THAT SOLVED PROBLEM-----------------

```
void createnewPerson(int assignID, RECT startingpoint, vector<Person>* allthePeople, int framenumber) {
    Person newguy(assignID, startingpoint, framenumber);

    std::cout << "New Person ID number: " << newguy.getIDnumber() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "New Person Recent Frame:  " << newguy.getlastframeseen() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "New Person Recent history bottom:  " << newguy.getrecenthistory().bottom << std::endl;
    int place = assignID - 1;

    if (allthePeople->size() > place)
    {
        //assuming places starts from 1 to vector's size.
        (*allthePeople)[place] = newguy;
    }
    else
    {
        allthePeople->push_back(newguy);
    }
}
```

Comment: As `allthePeople` is a pointer to a vector, you manipulate it using `allthePeople->...` (i.e. skip the ampersand). What is the reason you want to put the person at a specific place in the vector?

Comment: This is because once a person have left the screen and is no longer important, I clear its data. And instead of adding a new person to the end of the vector each time (which would end up with a very large vector, and lots of unnecesary stuff being stored), I want to add the new people to the first available position where nothing important is being stored.

Comment: If the ID is random, you can use `map` to store the objects instead of a `vector`.

Comment: The ID will typically be below 10, because once the person of ID number 1 is no longer on the screen, his data will be cleared and the ID number 1 will be assigned to the next person to enter.

Comment: Ok, you should probably change `vector<Person>* allthePeople` to `vector<Person>& allthePeople` as you aren't null checking it. Also, I don't think it makes a huge amount of sense to have a `Person` s assignID correspond to their index, it's probably better to use `vector::erase()` when a person should 'die' and `vector::push_back()` when a new person should be created.

Comment: You shouldn't really need to use pointers for your vectors. Pass them by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assign` is meant to **replace** the full content of a vector.

Assuming that you want to put every person in a specific place. You might then better use operator[]  to put the value at the place you want instead of using assign. You need to have the vector with the appropriate size.

```
if (allthePeople->size() >= place )
{
    //assuming places starts from 1 to vector's size.
    (*allthePeople)[place - 1] = newguy;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helped. I have added my final answer to the question with a slight changed to your code, and the inclusion of an "else" which is called if there is no space for a new element